# Como fazer post em Xml em Reacjs

Tags: xml, react, login, axios, auth

estou iniciando minha caminhada em Reactjs, e estou passando por um problema a alguns dias, que é fazer uma autenticação de login em um api externa na minha aplicação, para dar acesso ao usuário ao restante da aplicação.

Tentei fazer isso utilizando Axios e passando as informações por JSON, porem não deu certo, pois a API só aceita os dados sendo passados por POST, e por mais que eu pesquise na internet, não consigo achar o que esta faltando na estrutura que estou usando.

Segue meu código:

```
import api from "../../services/api";
import { login } from "../../services/auth";

class SignIn extends Component {

    state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        error: ""
    };

    handleSignIn = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        if (!email || !password) {
        this.setState({ error: "Preencha e-mail e senha para continuar!" });
        } else {
        try {
            const response = await api.post("login", { email, password });
            login(response.data.token);
            this.props.history.push("/menu");
        } catch (err) {
            this.setState({
            error:
                "Houve um problema com o login, verifique suas credenciais. T.T"
            });
        }
        }
    };
```

E os dados chegam assim:
[image: Request Payload]

[image: Preview]

E esse é meu arquivo WebPack:

```
{
  "name": "frontend3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "test": "jest ./test"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./test/enzyme.setup.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"
  }
}
```

Se alguém poder me ajudar ficarei super grato, estou estudando todos os dias para ficar bom no que faço, porem não tive JS antes de começar React, e isto tem me afetado em questões simples como esta.

Desde já gratidão por quem tiver tempo para ajudar.

Comment: Amigo da uma olhada nessa função: http://raathigesh.com/Converting-Json-Object-To-XML-String-In-JavaScript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem vindo ao SoPT!

Bom, considerando o seu problema, entendo que você esteja trabalhando com uma API que espera receber o formato [x-www-form-urlencoded](https://medium.com/@rajajawahar77/content-type-x-www-form-urlencoded-form-data-and-json-e17c15926c69), entretanto sua requisição com Axios está enviando sempre em JSON, conforme aparece no seu print da requisição correto?

Nesse caso **há duas coisas que precisam ser feitas**. Primeiro ponto, conforme o print da sua requisição seu [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) está definindo que o tipo de envio da requisição é `JSON`, **portanto precisamos alterar para o tipo de envio que deseja**, que nesse caso seria **x-www-form-urlencoded**.

Visto pela estrutura que postou, o trecho de código onde deve inserir o Contet-Type deve estar em outro arquivo que não postou (que é importado para 'api').

Como não sei como está seu código nesse arquivo não consigo lhe dar um exemplo concreto, mas é necessário que você insira o seguinte [Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) no Axios:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

Esse tópico do SO pode te ajudar: [Passando Headers com requisição POST no Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617825/passing-headers-with-axios-post-request-reactjs)

O segundo passo é que precisa utilizar [QueryString](https://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-e-exemplo-pratico-usando-querystring/18094) para converter seus parâmetros para o formato correto. Portanto sua linha de envio de parâmetros deverá ficar da seguinte forma:

```
const response = await api.post("login", 
   Querystring.stringify({ 
      "email": email,
      "password": password
   }));
```

Não se esqueça de importar o módulo query-string antes :)

```
const queryString = require('query-string');
```

Comment: Poxa era isso mesmo, apanhei um pouco para conseguir aplicar da maneira correta, mas funcionou.

Coloquei Content-type no header:

E o queryString onde tu me indicou, agora esta funcionado.


Muito obrigado, de verdade, salvou minha vida.

Comment: Adicionei com `yarn add query-string` e importei no react com `import * as QueryString from "query-string"` e funcionou, valeu!